# Transfer the QuerySet in Django AdminModel

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-admin

I'm trying to make a reference to another model with my sorting.

```
query = Cars.objects.filter(task_id__exact=obj.task_id, 
                            engine__isnull=False).values_list('engine', flat=True)
engines_ids_list=list(query)

link = reverse("admin:auto_engines_changelist") + f"?id={engines_ids_list}"
                                                               ^
                                                         Not work, it's example
```

`?engine_id=1&engine_id=2` display object with the last parameter (engine_id=2), not 2 objects..

work only `Engines.objects.filter(pk__in=engines_ids_list)`

How can I send this filter to the engine changelist page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass task_id as a params in url.

```
link = reverse("admin:auto_engines_changelist") + f"?task_id={task_id}"
```

then you can access the {task_id} value in get_queryset() method of Engines Modeladmin.

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    queryset = super().get_queryset(request)

    task_id = request.GET.get('task_id')
    if task_id is not None:
        engine_ids = Cars.objects.filter(task_id__exact=task_id, engine__isnull=False).values_list('engine', flat=True)
        queryset = queryset.filter(id__in=engine_ids)
    return queryset
```

Comment: It works only if I won't indicate task_id. If I specify it, Django redirect me to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/auto/engines/?e=1" with all objects. I tried to find what for "?e=1", but I did not find anything. At the same time, I checked the code executed correctly: 
`queryset = queryset.filter(id__in=engine_ids)
print(queryset) # <QuerySet [<Engine: 1>, <Engine: 2>]>
 `
EDIT:
 `link = reverse("admin:auto_engines_changelist") + f"?e={task_id}" `
with:
 `request.GET.get('e') `
work for me, but I do not understand why I can't stretch your own variable

Comment: @CbrRRider django admin url accept query-parameter of model field name. I think your **Engines**  model has not **task_id** field. So url redirect with **?e=1** param.